# MOV形式の動画へ、ウォーターマーク画像形式の文字列を埋め込みたいのですが

Tags: php

**やりたいこと**
・既にあるMOV形式の動画へ、「ウォーターマーク画像形式の文字列」を新たに埋め込みたい
※「同じ文字列の字幕」を、動画再生中ずっと表示させるようなイメージです

**質問背景**
・画像をアップロードしたらImageMagickでウォーターマークを入れるようにしているのですが、動画で似たようなことが出来ないかと思い質問しました

**質問**
・サーバサイド(PHPなど)で、実装することは可能？
・ソフトウェアで行わないと無理でしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

私なら FFMpeg を使うと思います。

[ffmpeg 動画にウォーターマーク（ロゴ）をつけてみる - 脳内メモ＋＋](http://fftest33.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-80.html)

静画がアップロードされたら、Imagemagick でウォーターマークを入れる、と同じように、
動画がアップロードされたら、FFMpeg でウォーターマークを入れる、
というイメージです。

[PHPでffmpegを使った動画の変換を裏側で行う - Qiita](http://qiita.com/kazukichi/items/c0516edb3898b469198b)

Comment: リンク先、初めて知りました(自分ではかなり検索したつもりだったのですが…)。参考になりました